# Where I can find an original Nusach Paras (Persian) Siddur?

Tags: prayer-book, nuschaot, nusach-edot-hammizrach

Where can I find a siddur with the original Persian (Parsi) Nusach (if such a siddur exists)?

Comment: Just out of curiousity- was the Parsi nusach changed at some point such that current siddurim would no longer reflect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here’s](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/20923) such a facsimile of a 16th century siddur (cf. pg. 40 of the book).