# What nusach is followed by Persian Jews

Tags: nuschaot, nusach-edot-hammizrach, persia

As far as I’m aware, there was originally a Persian nusach, but it no longer exists. If this is the case, what nusach do they follow?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/90336/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105137/759

Comment: See https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/20923 and https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%97_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A1

Answer (score 4):

I was just in Pico in Los Angeles last week and attended services there every day in a Persian Shul. They have their own Siddurim. I even bought a copy which has interlinear Persian translation. It's called Tefilat Ezra and it is the Ghermezian Edition. The service to me was pretty much indistinguishable from what you would expect in most Sephardi Shuls. I only spotted some very minor differences.

[image]

Comment: I have the interlinear English version of this one, the two biggest differences I've seen vs. most Sephardic siddurim is that they insert "El Melech Neeman" before the Kriyat shema hamita (as do Iraqi Jews) and don't include "v'ani tefillahti" before the Shabbat Minha Torah reading